# Are directives/instructions executed at runtime or assembly time?

Tags: assembly, masm, directive

I'm pretty new to assembly, and I'm wondering when directives and instructions are executed respectively?

Comment: Directives = assembly time, instructions = runtime (of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions are executed at run-time.

Directives are instructions for the assembler and thus are not really executed at all.

Comment: Although correct, directives are instructions for the assembler that **may** emit instructions that get assembled/linked and then executed at runtime. I have a suspicion you probably meant something like that when you said **not really**.