# Preprocessor directive not working on using namespace statements in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, conditional-statements, razor-pages

I have been able to successfully use preprocessor directives in chstml/razor pages like this:

```
@{#if !NETCOREAPP}
I AM NOT CORE. And many other things here.
@{#else}
I AM CORE.
@{#endif}
```

But, I have not been able to use it to selectively include a  'using namespace' statement like this, in the beginning of the file:

```
@{#if !NETCOREAPP}
    @using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@{#endif}
```

When I do the above, compiler seems to simply ignore the #ifs and is giving me this error, when compiling in a Core project (where NETCOREAPP is defined):

```
The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have tried other syntaxes of #ifs and everywhere I am facing the same issue wiht the using namespace.

I also have a similar issue with hiding @inherits statements as well.

It seems like @inherits and @using statements cannot be hidden using conditional compilation symbols. If so, it would be good to know if there are any workarounds to this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to share a cshtml file between a MVC Framework project and a MVC Core project, hence this requirement to hide the using and inherits directives from another.

(The following uses references to the `using` dire
In short, a `cshtml` file can be shared only if C# code within the file uses: namespace/classes defined in both the .NET Framework and .NET Core framework (and use the same method signatures producing the expected output in both frameworks); or namespace/class definitions imported into both projects that are independent of the framework (like your own namespace/class definitions).

Even if there's a way to "hide" the `using` directive from a framework, C# code in a Razor page could still be referencing namespaces/classes that are likely defined/shipped only in .NET Framework or .NET Core.

You could eliminate the `using` directive altogether and just use fully qualified namespace types, but [C# Intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-intellisense?view=vs-2022) will show a red squiggly underline for types if a Razor page is used in a project where the project's framework doesn't ship with the namespace package/library/file.

### C# preprocessor directives

The full list of preprocessor directives for C# is listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives). There isn't a directive listed that identifies a way to hide a `using` directive (i.e. not have the directive included based on the project type).

### 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

> When I do the above, compiler seems to simply ignore the #ifs and is giving me this error, when compiling in a Core project

The `System.Web.Mvc` namespace is part of the .NET Framework but not part of .NET Core. This is why the error you listed, "The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'", results when the `using` directive for `System.Web.Mvc.Html` occurs in the .NET Core project.

Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web?view=netframework-4.8) for the `System.Web` namespace in .NET Framework 4.8 lists the following:

> For .NET Core and .NET 5+, this namespace contains the HttpUtility class.

> For .NET Framework, this namespace contains classes and interfaces that enable browser-server communication. These classes include the HttpRequest class, which provides extensive information about the current HTTP request; the HttpResponse class, which manages HTTP output to the client; and the HttpServerUtility class, which provides access to server-side utilities and processes. System.Web also includes classes for cookie manipulation, file transfer, exception information, and output cache control in .NET Framework.

### `using` directive

For clarity in reference to a `using` *[directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)* versus a `using` *[statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)*

The purpose of a `using` directive, as defined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive), is to:

> use types defined in a namespace without specifying the fully qualified namespace of that type. In its basic form, the using directive imports all the types from a single namespace.

> Create a `using` directive to use the types in a namespace without having to specify the namespace.

```
using System.Text
```

This [reference](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2923212&seqNum=3) provides a clearer definition:

> Fully qualified namespace names can become quite long and unwieldy. It is possible, however, to import all the types from one or more namespaces into a file so that they can be used without full qualification. To achieve this, the C# programmer includes a using directive, generally at the top of the file.

The same Microsoft documentation adds the following as a side note:

> The `using` keyword is also used to create using statements, which help ensure that IDisposable objects such as files and fonts are handled correctly

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(manyLines))
{
}
```

### Conditional compilation

The C# language specification for [conditional compilation directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#655-conditional-compilation-directives) says

> #if, #elif, #else, and #endif, which are used to skip conditionally sections of source code (§6.5.5)

Is the `using` directive considered source code?

The comment from @Michael Petch in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291928/are-directives-instructions-executed-at-runtime-or-assembly-time) Stack Overflow post adds to understanding the `using` directive:

> directives are instructions for the assembler that may emit instructions that get assembled/linked and then executed at runtime.

A `using` directive is used by C# Intellisense when writing code (at design time) and later by they compiler.